# Lua alternating a value on a timer

Tags: lua

I am in quite a pickle right now.

I have a switch that I need to be able to turn on and off every second but I don't really know how I would do that because it needs to be applied on the same bit/function
If currently have a bit that functions as an on/off for a function, the problem is that I need a way for that function to turn itself on and off every 1 second.
I have tried this so far but it is not working for me.
Could anyone try and solve this issue for me please?

```
{$lua}
if not syntaxcheck then

  local On = 1
  local Off = 0
  local Switch = OnOffController

  local function OnOff()
    if Switch = Off then
      Switch = On
    if Switch = On then
      Switch = Off
    end
    end
  end

    OnOff()
    if(Second == nil) then
      Second = createTimer(getMainForm())
      Second.Interval = 1000
      Second.OnTimer = function(timer)
        OnOff()
      end
    end
  Second.setEnabled(true)
  end
```

Comment: Solved it, I used an else statement instead and that seems to work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

While there could be more wrong, there's definitely an issue with the OnOff() function:

```
local function OnOff()
    if Switch = Off then
      Switch = On
    if Switch = On then
      Switch = Off
    end
    end
end
```

The two nested `if` statements are not going to do what you want. First off, you're using the assignment operator `=` rather than the equals operator `==`. Even if that were correct though the logic has a problem. If `Switch` is `On` going into the first `if` the flow will bypass both. If `Switch` is `Off` going into the first `if` it'll first get changed to `On` and then immediately hit the second condition and get changed back to `Off`.

You probably want something more like:

```
local function OnOff()
    if Switch == Off then
        Switch = On
    else
        Switch = Off
    end
end
```

You don't need the second comparison at all assuming `Switch` can only be true or false.

Other bits of advice I'd give would be to use a boolean type for the `Switch` variable as that makes it explicit that it can only have two values. You'd probably also want to change its name to something like `SwitchedOn` or the like to make it obvious what true and false would mean in its context. Likewise a name like `ToggleSwitch` may make it a bit more obvious what the function presently called `OnOff` is intended to do.